# Port forwarding using Apache and a Virgin Media Super Hub 2?

Tags: apache

I have created a website which i'd like to host on my own Web Server, to do this I've installed Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi and loaded Apache and configured it correctly (if i hit my IP i get the index page)

However, i'm having issues port fowarding on my Virgin Media Super Hub 2 and i'm struggling to find any steps on how to set this up correctly and what address i need to hit post port forward? Any suggestions?

Comment: Having same issue- did you find a solution?

Comment: Afraid not, but, we ended up using an external host anyway for our website, it grew much quicker than we first thought anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. Probably you changed the dhcp pool in order to configure and use some static IP (and you did it right) but it seems that this crappy hub doesn't like to do portforward to ips out of the hdcp lease.

**Solution in my case:** get the DHCP config back to the original range of 253 hosts and, to make sure you don't have your static ip assigned by DHCP you can make reservations adding the mac address.

I was not able to find this solution online, so I hope this help someone!